# Facebook SDK : logging out automatically

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to build a page that when loaded logs out automatically the user from facebook

i tried this code

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'abc123456789',
        xfbml      : false,
        version    : 'v2.7',
        status     :  true
    });
    FB.logout();
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

but it does not work. It seems that when FB.logout() is called, the FB api doesn't know the user's session.

If I call FB.logout() after an arbitrary period of time

```
setTimeout(function(){
     FB.logout();
}, 3000);
```

It works.
Is there a way to know when the user information loading has been completed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FB.getLoginStatus` to check if the user is logged in. It should work to call `FB.logout` in the callback function of `FB.getLoginStatus`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

For example:

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'abc123456789',
    xfbml      : false,
    version    : 'v2.7',
    status     :  true
});
FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.logout();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: FB.getLoginStatus() always returns undefined

Comment: do you have a test link? getLoginStatus does not only check for the login, it also refreshes the user session. so IF you are logged in correctly, it should work.

Comment: Try passing true to getLoginStatus as second parameter (that makes it actually do a new request to check the status with Facebook, whereas without that it might rely on a cached status.)